# Fancyhdr header : chapter, subsection and subsubsection appearing on the header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am trying to create a LaTeX template with a specific header.
Here is what I am trying to do :

- Left odd : \subsubsection
- Right odd : My name, I can deal with this one :)
- Left even : \subsection
- Right even : \chapter

For each title, I only want the title and not "Chapter 1 : chaptername".

I have used this :

```
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionmark}[1]{\markleft{#1}}
```

But it does only work for two titles, right ?

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{[ACaslonPro-Regular.otf]}
\newfontfamily{\acasSb}{ACaslonPro-Semibold.otf}
\newfontfamily{\acasB}{ACaslonPro-Bold.otf}
\newfontfamily{\acasR}{ACaslonPro-Regular.otf}

\newfontfamily{\frutL}{FrutigerLTStd-Light.otf}
\newfontfamily{\frutB}{FrutigerLTStd-Bold.otf}
\newfontfamily{\frutR}{FrutigerLTStd-Roman.otf}


\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=160mm, left=22mm, right = 20mm, top = 20mm, bottom = 22mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionmark}[1]{\markleft{#1}}

\fancyhead[LO]{\fontsize{8}{12} \selectfont \acasB \textsc{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\fontsize{8}{12} \selectfont \acasB \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\fontsize{8}{12} \selectfont \acasB \textsc{\leftmark}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{This should be on right even}
\section{This should not appear at all}
\subsection{This should be on left even}
\subsubsection{This should be on odd left}

\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I have found :

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{[ACaslonPro-Regular.otf]}
\newfontfamily{\acasSb}{ACaslonPro-Semibold.otf}
\newfontfamily{\acasB}{ACaslonPro-Bold.otf}
\newfontfamily{\acasR}{ACaslonPro-Regular.otf}

\newfontfamily{\frutL}{FrutigerLTStd-Light.otf}
\newfontfamily{\frutB}{FrutigerLTStd-Bold.otf}
\newfontfamily{\frutR}{FrutigerLTStd-Roman.otf}


\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=160mm, left=22mm, right = 20mm, top = 20mm, bottom = 22mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\let\Subsubsectionmark\subsubsectionmark
\def\subsubsectionmark#1{\def\Subsubsectionname{#1}\Subsubsectionmark{#1}}

\let\Subsectionmark\subsectionmark
\def\subsectionmark#1{\def\Subsectionname{#1}\Subsectionmark{#1}}




\fancyhead[LO]{\fontsize{8}{12} \selectfont \acasB \textsc{\Subsubsectionname}}
\fancyhead[RO]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\fontsize{8}{12} \selectfont \acasB \Subsectionname}
\fancyhead[RE]{\fontsize{8}{12} \selectfont \acasB \textsc{\leftmark}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{This should be on right even}
\section{This should not appear at all}
\subsection{This should be on left even}
\subsubsection{This should be on odd left}

\lipsum[1-8]



\end{document}
```

The only drawback : it seems that I cannot use \textsc on \leftmark in order to have a small caps chapter name. If anyone knows how to deal with this, I would really appreciate !

Comment: This will occasionally fail, if the page breaking algorithm pushes a [sub]subsection to the next page, after it had already been used to set the corresponding macros. That's the reason marks were invented. Either use an extra mark with the `extramarks` package, or use the marks for subsection//subsubsection and put the chapter title in a macro.